# AudioKit - no sound output

Tags: ios, swift, audio, audiokit

I try to use AudioKit to ouput a pure sine wave.
https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit
I've tried to set up a new project like on there homepage, and also tried there "Hello World" Example, included in the AudioKit Download.

Both builds fine, and the Hello World example displays the generated sine wave, correctly on the screen, but there is no sound playing, I can't hear anything. I've set the volume to max and tried with other apps, if they were playing audio fine, and they do.
Are there any suggestions?

I am using Xcode 8.3.3 and as device an iPad Mini 2 with iOS 10.3.1

Thank you

Answer (score 17):

By default, AudioKit is configured to not play audio while the device is in silent mode. In order to do this, just add the following line before starting AudioKit:

```
AKSettings.playbackWhileMuted = true
try! AudioKit.start()
```