# AudioKit - Trying to generate sound in Audio Kit 5

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I am setting up a start application that on start up, will generate some white noise using AudioKit.

I have set up the following code that gets called on start up of my application:

```
let engine = AudioEngine()
let noise = WhiteNoise()
            
let mixer = Mixer(noise)
mixer.volume = 1

engine.output = mixer
try! engine.start()
```

But when I start up the application I do not hear any sound being generated. I set up a simple example to generate a sine wave using AVFoundation and I was able to hear the sound generated from my simulator.

I found an old thread - [AudioKit - no sound output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46250849/audiokit-no-sound-output) but I checked the AudioKit repo and it looks like this feature was removed a couple months back since it was not being used.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does it work if you call `noise.start()`?

Answer (score 1):

Try `noise.start()` Generators don't default to being on.

Comment: Not sure if I'm missing something but noise.start() did not work for me either. I tried placing it before and after the engine.start() call.

Comment: not totally sure what the issue was but looked into the AudioKit Cookbook code and used the NoiseGeneratorsView() as a reference and it worked now!